# Yii2 validation class ip does not exist

Tags: php, validation, input, yii2

I have install Yii2-basic framwork and i want to validate inputform allowed: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html 
Email, string validation all work well, but if i use IP validation, my Aplication throw error Class ip does not exist.

There is my code:
Model:

```
public function rules() {

    return [
    [['name','ipadress'],'required'],
            ['ipadress','ip']
            ];


}
```

There is my controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
 $model= new Router();
 if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
           Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','WORK WELL');
        } else {

            $error= $model->errors;

        }

                     return $this->render('index', [
            'list' => $list,
            'menu' => $menu->getMenu(),
               'model'=>$model,]);       

  }
```

And my View

```
 $form = ActiveForm::begin();
                        echo $form->field($model,'name');
                        echo $form->field($model,'ipadress');


?>
                        <?=  Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

If i try validate email in rules, all works well:

```
return [
[['name','ipadress'],'required'],
        ['ipadress','email']
        ];
```

Please can somebody help with this problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: IpValidator is available since `2.0.7` - maybe you have got older version?

Comment: use composer update and try a gain.

Comment: ok thank you i will try update and let you know.

Comment: Biley you are right, thank you "!! i had version 2.0.2